# Saved entities within unit test, don't seem to exist within the application context

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-3.5

**model.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
...
Base = declarative_base()

class Team(Base):
    id = Column(String, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

**test_app.py**

```
from model import Team, Session, engine
class TestApp(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.connection = engine.connect()
        self.trans = self.connection.begin()
        self.session = Session(bind=self.connection)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.session.close()
        self.trans.rollback()
        self.connection.close()

    @patch('realtime_bot.rtmbot.RtmBot.start')
    def test_app_creates_one_rtmbot(self, mck):
        team = Team('1', 't1')
        self.session.add(team)
        self.session.commit()
        app = MyApp()
        app.start()
        self.assertEqual(len(app.bots), 1)
```

When I set a debugger in this test, I can see the in memory db has indeed one Team entity.

But once app.start() kicks in, the db is already empty again.

**MyApp.py**

```
from src.model import Session, Team
class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self, directory):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.bots = []
        self.session = Session()

    def start(self):
        teams = self.session.query(Team).all()
```

I suppose this has to do with session perhaps?  But I'm importing both from models, hence it should be the same instance. I'm a bit stuck here, would appreciate some help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems not many are using pure SQLAlchemy without Flask-alchemy extension.

I finally found the solution.

As I had suspected, the key is to use the same session within unit test and the app itself.

**MyApp.py**

```
from src.model import Session, Team, engine
class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self, directory):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.bots = []
        self.connection = engine.connect()
        self.session = Session(bind=self.connection)
```

And in unit test class:

```
class TestApp(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.connection = engine.connect()
        self.trans = self.connection.begin()
        self.app = MyApp()
        self.session = self.app.session
```